# C# Array Copy from Utils.CopyArray, my source code won't convert

Tags: c#

I am currently using this in my C# code:

```
numArray = (int[])Utils.CopyArray(numArray, new int[num3 + 1]);
```

I would like to switch to Array.Copy but can't figure out how without making errors (index out of range, etc).

UPDATED CODE TO SHOW MORE DEPTH

```
            var num3 = 0;
            int[] numArray = { };
            var mediafileName = @"";

            for (var j = 0; j <= PlayListGrid.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
            {
                if (!Equals(Convert.ToString(PlayListGrid.Rows[j].Cells["Song"].Value), @""))
                {
                    num3++;
                    numArray = (int[])Utils.CopyArray(numArray, new int[num3 + 1]);
                    numArray[num3] = j;
                }
                else
                {
                    mediafileName = Convert.ToString(PlayListGrid.Rows[j].Cells["MediaFileName"].Value);
                }

                table.Rows.Add((j + 1).ToString(), @"",
                    Convert.ToString(PlayListGrid.Rows[j].Cells["Artist"].Value),
                    Convert.ToString(PlayListGrid.Rows[j].Cells["Title"].Value),
                    Convert.ToString(PlayListGrid.Rows[j].Cells["DiscId"].Value),
                    mediafileName,
                    Convert.ToString(PlayListGrid.Rows[j].Cells["Time"].Value),
                    Convert.ToString(PlayListGrid.Rows[j].Cells["TimeLengthSecs"].Value));
            }
```

Comment: You need to provide a [MCVE] showing your attempt with Array.Copy and specifically explain what goes wrong.

Comment: [`Array.Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?view=net-5.0) has overloads that allow you to specify start index, length, etc.

Comment: @xanatos See [Utils.CopyArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.compilerservices.utils.copyarray?view=net-5.0) it's a VB.Net function

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that doesn't throw an exception, but returns false on failure. But I don't recommend it because, with exceptions, you can find and solve errors very well. I hope I understand the question right.

```
public static bool CopyArray<T>(ref T[] output, T[] arr) {
    try {
        T[] tmp = output;
        Array.Copy(tmp, arr);
        output = tmp;
        return true;
    catch {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
int num3 = 0; // your value
int[] numArray = null; // your value
CopyArray(ref numArray, new int[num3 + 1]);
```